Disable tooltips / balloon

Is there an option to disable them? I am using Mathematica 14 on Windows 11.

try as suggested in answer to how-to-disable-the-small-pop-up-windows-when-mouse-is-over-a-mathematica-command  which is SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CodeAssistOptions -> {"FloatingElementEnable" -> False}]  btw, this is the most annoying feature in Mathematica ever made. No body  seems to like it. Except Wolfram himself :)

@Nasser I use them all the time. Shortcut to the docs is great and the tongue showing the usage statements sometimes is a fast way to avoid opening the docs if I just need to be reminded of the function's syntax.
